# pdfBox: how to get signing name from signature field

Tags: java, pdfbox

Using itext I can get the signing name (Signed By) like this:

```
fields = reader.getAcroFields();

pk = fields.verifySignature(FieldName);

name = pk.getSignName();
```

How do I get the signing name using pdfBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getSignatureDictionaries()` gets the signatures, and `PDSignature.getName()` gets the name. To see more, have a look at the [ShowSignature.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/ShowSignature.java?view=markup) example from the source code download in the examples subproject.